# Не работают горячие клавиши tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

tmux установлена на Ubuntu 16.04. работают не все горячие клавиши, при этом полные команды срабатывают. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: какие команды работают? какие клавиши работают? какие нет?

Comment: Начиная вплоть от ошибок БСВВ (BIOS), отсуствия или неправильной работы драйвера в ядре, ненастроенной реакции на события в user space...